# How can I increment and decrement value with unique id?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have this loop, The id is unique. When I try to increment it is working for only one input field. How can I increment and decrement using unique id?

```
          @forelse($allproduct as $key=>$data)
                            <tr>
                                <td data-label="@lang('Date')">
                                     <div class="quantity col-md-8" style="display:flex; ">
                                          <input type="text" value="" class="form-control req amnt display-inline" id="qtyid[{{$data->product_id}}]" min="0">
                                       <div class="quantity-nav">
                                          <div class="quantity-button quantity-up qty" onclick="incrementValue()">+</div>
                                          <div class="quantity-button quantity-down qty" onclick="decrementValue()">-</div>
                                       </div>

                                    </div>
                                 </td>
                            </tr>
          @endforelse
```

**Javascript**

```
function incrementValue()
    {
        var value = parseInt(document.getElementById("qtyid").value, 10);
        value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
        value++;
        document.getElementById('qtyid').value = value;
    }


    function decrementValue()
    {
        var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('qtyid').value, 10);
        value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;

        value--;
        if(value == -1) {
            value = 0;
        }
        document.getElementById('qtyid').value = value;
    }
```

Comment: IDs have to be unique. All input fields in the loop have the same ID `qtyid`. That doesn't work.

Comment: I know. I asked how to make the id unique in function?

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with that code? Are you facing a PHP or a Javascript problem?

Comment: When I try to increment it is working for only one input field. How can I increment and decrement using unique id

Comment: "How can I increment and decrement using unique id" - why not start with using a unique ID? Also, if this is not related to PHP or Laravel itself, please share the generated markup, along with your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: I already make the Id unique. And also use the laravel code. I don't know what are you even talking about.

Comment: Then please share more details about your problem. If your elements hold an ID like `qtyid[4]`, your JS code needs to reflect this. Accessing the values through the ID `qtyid` is obviously not possible

Comment: Bro, that was my question. I had the id unique in html, but i couldn't use the unique id in JS. So I asked the question how to that. But nvm all good now. I got the answer. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use an approach that doesn't need IDs.

```js
function incrementValue(e)
    {
        // use the quantity field's DOM position relative to the button that was clicked
        const qty = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector("input.req.amnt");
        var value = parseInt(qty.value, 10);
        value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
        value++;
        qty.value = value;
    }


    function decrementValue(e)
    {
        const qty = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector("input.req.amnt");
        var value = parseInt(qty.value, 10);
        value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;

        value--;
        if(value == -1) {
            value = 0;
        }
        qty.value = value;
    }
```

```html
@forelse($allproduct as $key=>$data)
                            <tr>
                                <td data-label="@lang('Date')">
                                     <div class="quantity col-md-8" style="display:flex; ">
                                          <input type="text" value="" class="form-control req amnt display-inline" min="0">
                                       <div class="quantity-nav">
                                          <div class="quantity-button quantity-up qty" onclick="incrementValue(event)">+</div>
                                          <div class="quantity-button quantity-down qty" onclick="decrementValue(event)">-</div>
                                       </div>

                                    </div>
                                 </td>
                            </tr>
          @endforelse
```

Comment: It is showing Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined

Comment: Oops, in the html it should be passing `event` and not `e` - try now.